# Get logged-in username inside aspect in struts2-spring2.5 web application

Tags: java, spring, struts2, aop, aspect

I have a web application built on struts2 and spring2.5.
It uses the MVC nature of struts and security, Dependency Injection, AOP from spring.

I have used an aspect for logging operation which runs before any method is called.
But by no way I am able to log the logged-in username.
What I want is that the username should be logged whenever a method is called along with the method signature and method parameters.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Where username is stored? Show your aspect.

Comment: This is StackOverflow, please show executable code, i.e. at least the aspect and a class with method(s) it should be applied to. Optimally, provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You will get much better and faster help if you ask more precisely.